# The current domain is not authorized for OAuth operations

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, vercel

hello everyone i have vite app and i used firebase google auth . it works fine but when i deploy it on vercel it give me this error :

The current domain is not authorized for OAuth operations. This will prevent signInWithPopup, signInWithRedirect, linkWithPopup and linkWithRedirect from working. Add your domain (todomarwenlabidi.vercel.app) to the OAuth redirect domains list in the Firebase console -> Auth section -> Sign in method tab.

this is my app link : https://todomarwenlabidi.vercel.app/

and i added the domain to authorized domains
[look this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWtKA.png)

and this is my firebase config file :

```js
const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey:import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY ,
        authDomain: "todo-app-97ae2.firebaseapp.com",
        projectId: "todo-app-97ae2",
        storageBucket: "todo-app-97ae2.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "540711457418",
        appId:import.meta.env.VITE_APP_ID ,
};
```

Comment: Is your question solved? 
then please set this question as solved!

Answer (score 6):

You have to add the domains you use in the firebase authorized domains (see [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qvcx3.png))

[image]

Comment: What do we do if that is already done and it still doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was receiving the error is because I was running 127.0.0.1 rather than localhost