# Firebase Auth domain not authorized error despite being on Firebase console

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase auth in a wpf app, using the nugget package FirebaseAuth.net. I also implemented Dependency injection, but when I try to create an account, it says:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Auth domain is not among the authorized ones

I researched on Google and found this guide (https://9to5answer.com/firebase-this-domain-is-not-authorized)

[stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74131757/the-current-domain-is-not-authorized-for-oauth-operations#:%7E:text=The%20current%20domain%20is%20not%20authorized%20for%20OAuth,-%3E%20Auth%20section%20-%3E%20Sign%20in%20method%20tab.)

So, my domain, need to be authenticated in firebase\

What I do not understand is that the firebase domain that I am using is in fact on firebase

I have an appsetting.json inside y app, with ID, database URL, and my domain

```
{
  "FIREBASE_KEY": "xxxx",
  "FIREBASE_DOMAIN": "transcribed-c69c8.firebaseapp.com",
  "DATABASEURL": "xxxxx"

}
```

and then I have this in my app.cs

```
private readonly IHost _host;
private FirebaseAuthConfig? config;
private string? DatabaeURL;

public App() {

    //For debugging purposes

    //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en");

    SyncfusionLicenseProvider.RegisterLicense(ConstantsHelpers.SYNCFUSION_KEY);

    _host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
            DatabaeURL = context.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DATABASEURL");
            string? FireDomain = context.Configuration.GetValue<string>("FIREBASE_DOMAIN");
            string? FireKey = context.Configuration.GetValue<string>("FIREBASE_KEY");

            config = new FirebaseAuthConfig() {

                ApiKey = FireKey,
                AuthDomain = FireDomain, // Ovbiously when I get here, I can see my domain fetch from my json
                Providers = new FirebaseAuthProvider[] {
                  new EmailProvider()
                }
            };

            services.AddSingleton((services) =>
            new SignUpLoginWondow(config, DatabaeURL!));

            // Register another window
            services.AddSingleton((services) => new MainWindow());
        })
        .Build();
}

protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) {

    var uid = await LoginWithSavedDataAsync();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uid)) {
        MainWindow = _host.Services.GetRequiredService<MainWindow>();
        MainWindow.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel(uid!, DatabaeURL!);
    } else {
        MainWindow = _host.Services.GetRequiredService<SignUpLoginWondow>();
    }

    MainWindow.Show();
    base.OnStartup(e);
}
```

and if you go to the firebase console, my domain is there

[image: Fibase Domains]

To be able to create a user or get authenticated